# A sufficient condition for the converse of Lagrange's Theorem and need an example not to be cyclic, abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^{n}m$, $(p,m)=1$ such that every $p$-subgroup is normal. Prove that for every $d \mid p^{n}m$, there is a subgroup having the order $d$.

Proof:

We will prove it by induction on the order of $G$.

If the order of G is equal to 1 then the theorem is hold.
Assume that theorem is hold for all groups $G$ having the order smaller than $p^{n}m$. Let $d \, \vert \, p^{n}m$, then $d=p^{\alpha}\beta$, where $(\beta,p)=1$ and $\beta \, \vert \, m$. 
By hypothesis, one has H is a Sylow-subgroup, so the order of H is $p^{n}$. Hence there is a subgroup $H_{1}$ of H  having the order of $p^{\alpha}$. $H_{1}$ is normal by hypothesis.

Now consider the quotient group $G / H_{1}$ has the order of $p^{n-\alpha}m$ which has a normal Sylow-subgroup $H/H{1}$. By inductive hypothesis, we have a subgroup $S^{*}$ of $G / H_{1}$ of order $\beta$.
But we have a subgroup S of $G$ such that $S/H_{1}=S^{*}$ (To prove this, consider surjective group homomorphism $\pi \,:\,G \rightarrow G/H_{1}$). It follows that S is a subgroup of G and $\vert \, S \, \vert=p^{\alpha}\beta=d$.

I think this condition is strong, I only find examples satisfy this condition: cyclic, abelian. Can you find another?

Answer (score 0):

Well this just the Sylow's theorem which is just the partial converse for the Lagrange theorem.

Another partial converse is the Cauchy's theorem which states that if $G$ is a finite group and $p$ (here p is a prime) divides $|G|$ then $G$ has an element of order $p$ .

Well even with the added condition your proof is right.

Comment: Oh no, my proof for the order of $|G|=p^{n}m$ with above condition, then if $d | |G|$ then G has a subgroup of order d. @Remember me

Comment: Which condition are you talking about

Comment: Such that every p-subgroup is normal that mean if S is a subgroup of G and the order of S is $p^{k}$, $1 \leq k \leq n$, then S is normal subgroup.

Comment: As much as I see I think I cannot find any fault in your argument